# Не работает pyinstaller с python pygame игрой

Tags: python, pygame, exe, pyinstaller

Я пытаюсь компилировать python pygame игру используя pyinstaller.

Всё компилируется, все нужные папки создаются.

Когда я запускаю саму программу открывается консоль пишет hello from pygame открывается окно pygame но игра не работает хотя когда я запускаю через консоль всё работает.

В игре используется всего 2 файла:

один-это вся игра

второй-это иконка для будущего .exe файла

Comment: В каком-то ВУЗе зачётная неделя? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1100735/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9

Comment: какой  ВУЗ мне всего 14

Comment: Я тебе в прошлый раз предложил использовать cx_Freeze. Не получилось с его помощью?

Comment: @alexp в прошлый раз всё сработало, а в этот раз начала возникать ошибка с версией

Comment: @alexp сейчас всё отправлю

Comment: `File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32verstamp.py", line 127, in stamp
    raise ValueError("--version must be a.b.c.d (all integers) - got %r" % ver)
ValueError: --version must be a.b.c.d (all integers) - got 'VERSION_NUMBER e.g. 0.1'`

 вот что пишет в консоли когда я использую cx_Freeze

Comment: @alexp ладно я всё уладил

Comment: @alexp а как можно упаковать папку lib файл python37.dll и *.exe в один .exe файл

Comment: Версия должна конвертироваться в число, т.е. "1.0.2" например. Без букв внутри. Упаковать cx_Freeze в один файл не получится(по крайней мере я не помню такой опции), но я не вижу в этом особого смысла. Всегда можно создать архив, в том числе самораспаковывающийся.